# Mac Mini server - Dual screens?

Tags: display, thunderbolt-display, server.app, dual-screen

I'd like to setup dual screens on the new Mac Mini OS X Lion server, however as I understand it you need to use the HDMI port and the thunderbolt port. The only problem I have is I'm already using the thunderbolt port for a thunderbolt drive.

Will a HDMI splitter work? Or a thunderbolt splitter?
The thunderbolt drive has an extra thunderbolt port in the back (2, I'm only using 1), can I connect the other monitor to that, will that work? I doubt it but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Or, is there another way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can daisy chain up to 6 Thunderbolt devices from a single port, so you can connect the display via an adapter to that without any problems.

Comment: Thank you! :) After reading your answer I decided to plug it in to the thunderbolt drive (seeing as it's technically an adapter) and it works brillaintly! :)